# Mobile application without ViewNavigator

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm making a mobile application with abobe air and flex.
I want to know if it's possible to do it without ViewNavigator, or at least for some part, use something else.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can if you want to.  The views are there to improve mobile viewing however.  I believe the big point of it is for the use of the 'back' button since each view is added to a queue.

I say you should use it where needed since it was made for that kind of thing.

Comment: By adding whatever component you want in there?  I don't understand what you're asking...